# Create pointer to "this" object

Tags: c++, constants

I seem to be having issues in a project trying to create a pointer to "this" where "this" is the first LinkedList in a list in C++.  The first object has data in it, second does...etc until the `this->m_next` is `NULL`

The compiler is spitting this out at me:

`linkedlist.hpp:55:22: error: invalid conversion from âconst LinkedList<int>* constâ to âLinkedList<int>*â [-fpermissive]`

What am I doing wrong?

```
template <typename T>  
int LinkedList<T>::size() const
{
  int count = 0;
  LinkedList* list = this; // this line is what the compiler is complaining about

  //adds to the counter if there is another object in list
  while(list->m_next != NULL)
  {
    count++;
    list = list->m_next;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The member function is marked `const`. Which means that `this` is `const` as well. You need to do:

```
const LinkedList<T>* list = this; // since "this" is const, list should be too
//               ^
//               |
//               Also added the template parameter, which you need, since "this"
//               is a LinkedList<T>
```

Comment: So I have a quick question.  When the const is in front are you making a pointer to a constant object?   or are you making a constant pointer to an object?

Comment: When the `const` is in front like that, it's a "Pointer to a `const LinkedList<T>`" (a pointer to a constant object)

Comment: and when it is after then it is a constant pointer (aka it can't be re-pointed)

Comment: @MasterGberry: Yeah, when the `const` is after the `*`, then it's a "constant pointer to (whatever type of object)".

Comment: Also note that, for example, `const int*` is the same as `int const*` (notice in both of these the `const` is *before* the `*`, so they're both "pointers to a constant integer"). However, `int* const` is a "constant pointer to an integer" (since it has the `const` *after* the `*`).

Comment: Generally, I find doing `int const*` and `int*const` to be less confusing than `const int*` -- if you always do `const` *after* the thing you want to `const`, the pattern is clear.  The one exception is that if you `const` has nothing to its left... which is `const int*`.  By avoiding `const int*`, the pattern is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
LinkedList* list = this; // this line is what the compiler is complaining about
```

to

```
LinkedList<T> const * list = this; 
          ^^^ ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
LinkedList* list = this;
```

to

```
const LinkedList<T>* list = this; 
^^^^^           ^^^
```

Since your **function is defined as `const`**, the `this` pointer is automatically **of type `const LinkedList<T>*`**

Thus you **cannot assign a `const` pointer to a non `const` pointer**, explaining the error.

The missing `<T>` would likely give you errors if you try non `int` parameters.